# What should I do when events conflicted between JQuery plugins?

Tags: jquery, selectable

I have tow plugins attach to the `parent element` and `its children`.

parent attached with `JQuery UI selectable plugin` and its children attached with a plugin called [jquery contextmenu](http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/09/jquery-context-menu-plugin/).

With the `jquery contextMenu plguin`,there is a `mousedown event` with `$.stopPropagation()` function applied.

partial of the contextMenu code:

```
(this).mousedown( function(e) {
    var evt = e;
    evt.stopPropagation();
    $(this).mouseup( function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
        // more code below...
});
```

But at the same time,the `JQuery UI selectable` seems to use the `mousedown event` to make elements selection,so,because the `contextMenu` ,the `selectable plugin` couldn't make selection any more.

Now,I had to `remove the code $.stopPropagation() of contextMenu` and the `selectable plugin` work again and I hope this way didn't break the `contextMenu plugin`.

And finally , what should I do to make them work together without modify the code,because it is danger to do this??

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried simply "return false" from the event handler? This would contain the propagation.